# ERROR: For req: Pylette. Error installing weel. Trying to install outside the target directory

Tags: python, color-palette

I'm trying to install Pyllete package to extract image color palettes. I tried with:

`pip install --user Pylette`

I got:

```
ERROR: For req: Pylette.
The wheel 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-unpack-lr6tc1p6\\Pylette-0.4-py3-none-any.whl'
has a file 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\Pylette\\aux.py'
trying to install outside the target directory 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages'
```

I know it should be a problem of Python version: Pylette should work with versions <Python 3.

Let me know how can I solve this. Best!

Comment: The issue is that `aux.py` is not a valid filename on Windows; it's a reserved filename: https://github.com/NeuralEnsemble/PyNN/pull/678 You'll have to change it yourself, or get the creators to fix their project.